# Orthogonal matrices and different norms

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I'm trying to understand the relation between orthogonal matrices and different norms through a few practice problems, but as they don't have a solution guide I've gotten particularly stuck on one.

Suppose $Q$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix. We let $x$ be an arbitrary $n$-vector. Then a simple norm relation I (think) I got right is that 
$$||Qx||_{2} = \sqrt{x^{T}Q^{T}Qx} = x$$

The more challenging norm I don't quite understand though, is if we define the Frobenius norm of an $n \times n$ matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ as $$||A||_{F} = \sqrt{\sum _{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{ij})^{2}}$$
Then with our $Q$ from above, what would $||QA||_{F}$ be? I tried to just plug in what the actual values would look like after matrix multiplication, but that didn't give me any intuitive idea as to what the result would be.

Answer (score 0):

Note the definition of the Frobenius norm you used, can also be rewritten as $\Vert A \Vert_F^2 = \text{trace}(A^TA)$.

By using this definition, we get:

$\Vert QA \Vert_F^2=\text{trace}((QA)^TQA)=\text{trace}(A^TQ^TQA)=\text{trace}(A^TA)=\Vert A \Vert_F^2$.

Hence, $\Vert QA \Vert_F = \Vert A \Vert_F$.

Intuitively, $Q$ is a rotation matrix and $\Vert x \Vert_F$ is the Euclidean length of the vector, so clearly the rotated vector $Qx$ has the same length as $x$.